# Entering the UAE as a Filipino citizen resident in Taiwan: do I need any documents besides my tourist visa?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, filipino-citizens, uae

I'm a Filipino citizen legally employed in Taiwan.

What documents do I need to prepare aside from a tourist visa and a plane ticket before flying to Dubai, UAE?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you need your passport.  You should also bring your residency permit or employment permit or whatever it is that lets you live in Taiwan.  You should also have your onward travel ticket with you to show the UAE immigration officer.